# IReports does not print length more than 297mm

Tags: jasper-reports

I using ireport 4.0.1. I made a receipt print which is more than 297mm but it cuts at exactly at 297mm all the time. Rest of the data are not getting printed. But when i save it as a pdf i could see all the data. I tried with different kinds of printers (Eg: Epson TM20 -Receipt printer) but no positive changes :( I am using "ignored pagination" in my jrxml file. Could someone help me solving it ?

Comment: make sure your report has a report footer and the height is equal to the A4 size it fixed my 2 years problem with receipt printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your design properties to more then your desired size.
Set your margins to be smaller.
Experiment with the orientation.

As for your printer itself- it should have the exact same settings and property aspects as these.

Note that it is most definetly a setup and size issue and more then likely NOT your printers.

Here is an image of the properties menu in iReport and to open it go to WINDOW on the top bar and click PALETTE.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried changing page height. To an extent it works, but detail band gets cut at some point :( Also, i have 4 systems with 2 systems running XP and the other 2 running windows 7 but it works so fine (before changing height) in one system without any problem (which is running XP). I really dont understand what makes it run in especially that system. All systems have the same driver.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? @deivarayanAZHAGAPPAN

Comment: I have that issue still but increasing the page height works to an extend but not complete.

Comment: Sorry @deivarayanAZHAGAPPAN i wasn't able to reply to this because a few people 'closed it' and deemed it a duplicate. Regardless- what problem are you stuck on now?

Comment: I have the details band cut when i print a longer receipt. I increased the length of the page and disabled the option "ignore pagination" to print longer receipts

Answer (score -2):

Your report need to have a report footer and the height is equal to the A4 size.

It fixed my 2 years problem with receipt printing